# converting char array into one int

Tags: c, gcc, int

I can't use atoi, need to do it digit by digit.. How do I save it in a int.. given a char* temp put it all in one int..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main () {

    char* temp = "798654564654564654";
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++) {

        printf("%d", temp[i] - 48);

    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: You say you can't use atoi, I'm assuming this is homework?

Comment: start from the leftmost digit, add it to a temporary accumulator, and for each digit multiply the accumulator by ten and add the current digit

Comment: that will give one whole int of any number.. int a = 798654564654564654;

Comment: I hope you're not going to try and store that number in a 32-bit int. It's fairly near the high end of a 64-bit long.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (temp[j])
    i = i*10 + temp[j++] - '0';
```

However, take to account that your number is very big, so for `i` the `long long int` type is more appropriate.

Comment: Note that 798654564654564654 is bigger than an int can hold, so if you're seeing odd results from the above, try it with a smaller number, such as 123456;

Comment: i tried it with this char* temp = "1010"; gives me -1661074446

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<string.h>

int main() {    
   char* s = "798654564654564654";
   unsigned long long num = 0;    
   int i = 0, j = strlen(s);      
   for(i=0; i< j && s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9'; i++)     
       num = num * 10 + s[i] - '0';    
   printf("%lld",num);    
   return 0;    
}
```

It should work, Here is a [demo](http://codepad.org/xq3behZk).

---

**EDIT** : Here is an optimized sol :

```
unsigned long long latoi(char * s) {
   unsigned long long num = 0;
   while(*s>='0' && *s<='9') num = num * 10 + *(s++) - '0';
   return num;
}
```

And the [demo](http://codepad.org/1IuqYyf9).